# Need help in finding a regex in Java to capture date with all formats in a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with format given below, i want to capture the date from this string and then later parse it with a proper date format.

```
sometext username, 19/05/1985: some more text
sometext username2, 19-Sep-1985 23:59:59: some more text
```

Assumptions:

1. username will always succeeded by a coma ","
2. A date always ends with a colon
3. There may more text before and after the username and date strings.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use DateFormat?  It's locale sensitive, too.  Just tokenize the input string and worry about the parsing later.

Comment: "All formats" is hard to define. Do you have a complete list of the formats you expect?

Comment: Unless the terminating colon is the last in the string you won't be able to identify it.

Comment: You do realize that it may not be possible to distinguish mm/dd/yyyy from dd/mm/yyyy based on the values actually used.

Comment: If you just want the text between the comma and the colon, you can use: `,\s+(.*):` (See https://regex101.com/r/wM7vK8/1) But I am unsure from your question if that is really what you want?

Comment: All, thanks for your thoughts on this.. Yeah I was also feeling its impossible to identify the date but I later realized if I can get a Pattern that will capture something like this (19/05/1985) if only one colon (19/05/1985 23:59) for two colons and (19/05/1985 23:59:59) for three colons. I feel this is possible just not sure how..

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern-matcher to extract the date
Use `(?<=\w*, ).*(?=:)` as pattern to extract date 
and `dd/mm/yyyy` as date format

```
String str = "sometext username, 19/05/1985: some more text";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\w*, )\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}(?=:)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
m.find();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(m.group()));
```

**Output :**

```
Sat Jan 19 00:05:00 IST 1985
```

Comment: Durgpal thanks alot for your response, yet the pattern will not recognize the date and time if its in this format "19/05/1985 23:59:59" in the text given below "sometext username, 19/05/1985 23:59:59: somemoretext"

Answer (score 0):

Since my problem is unsolveable, and is more generic in nature. I had to change the input to HTML format. Something like `<b>username, 19-sep-2015 23:59:59:</b>`.

After doing this I was able to parse the date by capturing `,\s+(.*):<` and removing the last colon.